# Usage of "Don't Clear" in "Clear Flags" property of Camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

In Unity's [Camera](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html) component, there is a property *Clear Flags* which allows to choose from four options: Skybox, Solid Color, Depth Only and Don't Clear.

As documentation says:

> **Don’t clear**
>
> This mode does not clear either the color or the depth buffer. The
>   result is that each frame is drawn over the next, resulting in a
>   smear-looking effect. This isn’t typically used in games, and would
>   more likely be used with a custom shader.
>
> Note that on some GPUs (mostly mobile GPUs), not clearing the screen
>   might result in the contents of it being undefined in the next frame.
>   On some systems, the screen may contain the previous frame image, a
>   solid black screen, or random colored pixels.

---

*"This isn't typically used in games and would more likely be used with a custom shader"*

So my question is :

How to use it in a custom shader and What effects can be achieved by using it?

Has anyone ever used it or has a good explanation about the basic concept.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thread question is a bit old, however I had this problem and solved it.

I've made a Screen Image Effect that reproduces this effect, you can see it here:

https://github.com/falconmick/ClearFlagsMobile

Hope this helps!

Comment: Make sure if your pushing to IOS/Android that you include the shader in the list of shaders it always copies as it's dynamically found

Answer (score 4):

An idea would be those enemy encounter effects in Final Fantasy games. Look at the top edge of this gif to see the smearing effects of previous frames. This is probably combined with blur/rotation.

[image: gif]

Answer (score 0):

**"Paint!"**

It's a good question and has a solid answer! when you want to draw, you can set `ClearFlags` to `Don’t clear`. it's the most common usage of it.

I've created a tween and I want to show its ease functions, I can tween a white dot and set `ClearFlags` to `Don’t clear` to draw its plot! you can use it for debugging reasons and view the trajectory of objects!

int the picture below, I move a dot through the x direction and its y is a function of x value.

[image]